# Finding text of all WebElements that match a xpath using only one List

Tags: java, selenium

There is any way to find the text of WebElements that match a xpath by only using one List?
Normaly what I do is:

```
List<WebElement> listOfWe = driver.findElements(By.xpath("..."));
List<String> listOfStrings = new Array<>();
for (WebElement we:listOfWe ){
    listOfStrings.add(we.getText());
}
```

In that case I am using two Lists but I want to use only one. Does anybody know how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work for you:

```
final List<String> texts = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("...")).stream()
                                            .map(WebElement::getText)
                                            .collect(toList());
```